# Animated Ios Splash screen

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make my splash screen display 3 images after each other.

Ive tried multiple things but keep running into errors if anyone could see what i'm doing wrong in my code here?

```
@interface CydiaLoadingViewController : UIViewController
@end

%hook CydiaLoadingViewController
-(void)loadView {
%orig;
UIView *xiView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
xiView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
UIImageView *logo =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
logo.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 7;
[logo.imageView startAnimating];
logo.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2 - 60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2 - 90, 120, 120);
logo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
logo.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2 + 60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40)];
label.text = @"Cydia";
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30]];\
[xiView addSubview:logo];
[xiView addSubview:label];
[[self view] addSubview:xiView];
}

-(BOOL)hidesNavigationBar {
    return YES;
}
%end
```

the error

```
Tweak.xm:92:14: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'UIImageView *' with an
      rvalue of type 'NSArray *'
UIImageView *logo =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: added the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you assigned an instance of `NSArray` to an `UIImageView` variable at this line.

```
UIImageView *logo =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
```

As I understand, you want to use `UIImageView` to present these 3 images one by one. In this case, you should create `UIImageView` normally and use [`UIImageView`'s `animationImages` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621068-animationimages).

For example

```
UIImageView *logo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
logo.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
```